# Как изменить заголовок layout на разных страницах в Angular?

Tags: html, typescript, angular

Я работаю над учебным приложением. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня есть layout, который содержит заголовок h2, который хотелось бы изменить на других страницах. Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

layout.component.html

```
<div class="page">
  <app-menu></app-menu>
  <div class="page__container">
    <div class="page__title">
      <h2 class="title">
        ЗАГОЛОВОК
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="page__content">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Самое простое решение - сделать второй лейаут для других страниц, чтобы не накручивать кучу логики на лейаут

Comment: А что мешает эту часть кода писать на каждой странице?)